# Content of a SingleChildScrollView get undrawn when keyboard is open before the keyboard is completely open

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I noticed that having some content inside a SingleChildScroll view and having also a TextField inside it. If i start typing causing the keyboard to open the content under the keyboard get undrawn before the keyboard is completely open. Is that a flutter's bug or am i doing something wrong?
From [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/825vZ.gif) video you can see that the content under the keyboard becomes white before it ended open

There is my code

```dart
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          keyboardDismissBehavior: ScrollViewKeyboardDismissBehavior.onDrag,
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              TextField(),
              Container(
                height: 200,
                color: Colors.red,
              ),
              Container(
                height: 200,
                color: Colors.purple,
              ),
              Container(
                height: 200,
                color: Colors.yellow,
              ),
              Container(
                height: 200,
                color: Colors.green,
              ),
              Container(
                height: 200,
                color: Colors.blue,
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because `Scaffold();` is supposed to draw every widget above **keyboard** by default.
But adding the property `resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,` to `Scaffold();` override the default behaviour and hence return the result you're looking for.

Heres the *full code*

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
    resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          keyboardDismissBehavior: ScrollViewKeyboardDismissBehavior.onDrag,
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              TextField(),
              Container(
                height: 200,
                color: Colors.red,
              ),
              Container(
                height: 200,
                color: Colors.purple,
              ),
              Container(
                height: 200,
                color: Colors.yellow,
              ),
              Container(
                height: 200,
                color: Colors.green,
              ),
              Container(
                height: 200,
                color: Colors.blue,
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```